# Cómo sustituir Max()

Tags: c#, poo, visual-studio-2017

Hola gente lo que quiero hacer es sustituir el `.Max()` en c#. Quiero crear un método para llamar el último registro de la base de datos de producto y sumarle uno, en caso de que la base este vacía que me traiga uno.
A continuación les muestro el código que tengo.

```
public int ObtenerSiguienteCodigo()
{
    using (var context = new Quiosco2Container())
    {
        var resultado = context.Productos.OfType<Acceso_Datos.Producto>().Any()
            ? context.Productos.OfType<Acceso_Datos.Producto>().Max(x => x.Codigo) + 1
            : 1;

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias y espero ser claro en lo que necesito.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89359/discussion-on-question-by-estanislao-como-sustituir-max).

Answer (score 1):

Si no queres usar [Enumerable.Max](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2), un pequeño truco puede ser encontrarlo usando [Enumerable.OrderByDescending](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7.2), ya que con este, ordenas según el `Id`, así luego tomas el primero y lo incrementas.

Para ejemplificarlo,

Asumamos que tengo la siguiente clase

```
public class Ej
{
    public string o1 { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

y tengo la siguiente lista de objetos

```
IEnumerable<Ej> objList = new List<Ej>
{
    new Ej { o1 = "uno", Id = 1 },
    new Ej { o1 = "tres", Id = 3 },
    new Ej { o1 = "dos", Id = 2 },
    new Ej { o1 = "cinco", Id = 5 },
    new Ej { o1 = "cuatro", Id = 4 },
};
```

Para encontrar el siguiente id, lo podría hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
using System.Linq;
int nextId = objList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()?.Id+1 ?? 1;
```

1. Primero, uso [Enumerable.OrderByDescending](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7.2) para ordenar de mayor a menor, y de
   esa manera tomar el `Id` más alto.
2. Luego utilizo [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener, el objeto con el `Id` más alto, o `null` en su defecto.
3. En caso de ser `null`, asigno 1 a la variable `nextId`

Comment: Todo muy lindo.. ojala no tengas 3 millones de datos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi la manera óptima de hacer esto sería usar `Max()` o cual es?

Comment: creo que ninguna de estas maneras me resulta optima.. pero es mi opinion y necesitaria mas contexto.. tirarle el problema a EF en este caso me parece sobrecargar un lugar erroneo.. la db ya deberia saber cual es el maximo sin tanto lio.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal no uso lista uso base de datos SQLServer como lo haria si quiero tomar el ultimo registro en base de datos de la tabla Producto?

Comment: @Estanislao ¿no estas usando entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias ordernar descendente y tomar el primer de los codigos, si existe el valor lo tomas, sino al cero le sumas uno por lo tanto sera el primer codigo

```
public int ObtenerSiguienteCodigo()
{
    using (var context = new Quiosco2Container())
    {
        var codigo = context.Productos
                                .Select(x=>x.Codigo)
                                .OrderByDescending()
                                .FirstOrDefault();
        int ultimo = 0;

        if(codigo != null){
            ultimo = codigo;
        }

        return ultimo++;
    }
}
```

Igual sigo pensando que el `Max()` es la mejor opcion

```
public int ObtenerSiguienteCodigo()
{
    using (var context = new Quiosco2Container())
    {
        var resultado = context.Productos.Select(x => x.Codigo)
                                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                            .Max();

        return resultado++;
    }
}
```